# cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have to add spring security 3.2 to my  application, this are my configuration files:

```
Spring-security.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 

  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security  -->

<security:http  auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-     page="/auth/denied" >
<security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/login" access="permitAll"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/main/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

<security:form-login
login-page="/auth/login"
authentication-failure-url="/auth/login?error=true"
default-target-url="/main/common"/>

<security:logout
invalidate-session="true"
logout-success-url="/auth/login"
logout-url="/auth/logout"/>

</security:http>

<!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
<security:authentication-manager>
     <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
       <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
     </security:authentication-provider>
 </security:authentication-manager>

 <!-- Use a Md5 encoder since the user's passwords are stored as Md5 in the database -->
 <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"   id="passwordEncoder"/>

<!-- A custom service where Spring will retrieve users and their corresponding access    levels  -->
<!-- bean id="customUserDetailsService"    class="com.metmi.mmasgis.tutorial.service.CustomUserDetailsService"/-->
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
                     /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mmasgisServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
            </param-value>

        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mmasgisServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

    <filter> 
 <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
 <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class> 
 </filter> 


    <filter-mapping> 
 <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
 </filter-mapping> 

</web-app>
```

Running the application I get this error:`Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0];`

here you can see the full trace : http://pastebin.com/qfqq6Vdy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the logs seems that a bean with the id 'customUserDetailsService' is not defined.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'customUserDetailsService'
```

I see that your config you posted does have a bean named customUserDetailsService so I would check a few things.

- First ensure the configuration you posted matches your actual configuration.
- The configuration has the security configuration and the UserDetailsService in a single file. Is this actually how you have it configured?
- Are you using Global Method Security? If so, this has been known to trigger bugs with eager instantiation of beans relating to authentication. To figure it out, I will need to see this configuration as well.
- Randomly, try moving the customUserDetailsService bean before the rest of your security configuration. This really should not matter, but is more of an experiment.